# How do particle acquire thermal distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, simulations, equilibrium

Consider some toy N-body simulation: we start with a bunch of particles, discretize time, and simulate their interactions at each timestep. What numerical features should the simulation include to recover the equilibrium energy distribution of these particles with time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get equilibrium, whatever the initial condition is, the bunch of the particles must *forget* the initial configuration and velocities. This implies that the dynamics of the system and the observation time must allow the vanishing of the energy auto-correlation function.

From the technical point of view, we need a [*mixing* dynamical system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)). In practice, every interaction characterized by a strong repulsive core at short distances is sufficient for mixing dynamics, provided the density is not too high, and the temperature is not too low.

The limiting case of a harmonic solid is an example of a non-mixing system. In the harmonic approximation, each initial velocity distribution corresponds to the excitation of a subset of all the possible normal modes. Without strong anharmonic effects, such a distribution of normal modes remains unchanged in time. In such a case, thermal distribution of velocities is impossible. In the case of strong anharmonicity or fluid phases, the velocity thermalization is quite a fast process.